# Java -- how do I access (import) the class files in a folder that is in the same directory as the src folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar

In eclipse or netbeans or emacs pico or microsoft word or notepad or or or whatever. Thanks.

In eclipse, I'm trying to share a package in one project w/ another project. I do the whole buildpath->link source -> add source ... and it creates a linked directory but not as package within the src/ dir, instead as a separate dir sibling to the src/. so I'm left stranded, wondering, waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean classes without a package, you can only refer from them outward, you can't refer from a class that is in a package to a class with no package declaration (A very good thing).

Even if you wanted to reference a class in the default package it would be in your "src" folder, not in the same directory as your src folder, so perhaps you mean something different?

Generally your "src" directory would contain a "com" directory--the top of the package tree.  So if you had a class in the default package you would place it at the same level as "com", but as I said you can't refer to it from other code--you can only execute the unpackaged class from the command line.

If you are saying that you want all your classes in the same directory or something--then I recommend packaging them all together as a .jar file.

Comment: In eclipse, I'm trying to share a package in one project w/ another project. I do the whole buildpath->link source -> add source ... and it creates a linked directory but not as package within the src/ dir, instead as a separate dir sibling to the src/. so I'm left stranded, wondering, waiting for a solution. Or to abandon eclipse for the slightly less greener pastures of netbeans.

Comment: You should just be able to import the classes without dealing with classpaths or anything.  You probably also wan to to link the entire thing, don't try to link to the exact package directory you want, just say you want to require the other package.  A cleaner solution would be to create a third project with the shared packages and have both other projects import that project.

Comment: By the way, I would no longer call Netbeans worse than Eclipse.  In most ways it's a lot cleaner and it tends to be as fast (Used to be much slower).  The main difference is the lack of add-ons.  Eclipse has become the de-facto platform to repurpose for your own build toolkit (Like how Android does)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would add the project (with classes you want to share) to the Build Path (right-click>Build Path>Configure Build Path) of the consuming project.  That allows you to compile and run within eclipse.

If you want to create a link from one project to the place where the other project code lives, you have to create your linked folder in such a way that 1) it's already in the /src/ folder or 2) can be turned into a source folder and can see the full package structure necessary to compile your classes.  But that is not how most java projects consume the output of another java project.